# Use Object.factory without needing to cast to a specific type

Tags: d

I'm trying to create a similar router to Rails ActionDispatch router, which allows you to define a route similar to

```
map.get "/foo", :controller => "Foo", :action => "index"
```

which will then route `GET /foo` to `FooController#index`. With this structure in place you can use methods like

```
map.resources :foos
```

which will call methods like

```
map.get "/foo", :controller => "Foo", :action => "index"
map.get "/foo/:id", :controller => "Foo", :action => "show"
```

and so on.

In D, I've been able to figure out a lot of the reflexive code required to make this work, but not all of it.  In Ruby I can do:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    "FOOO BAR!"
  end
end

f = Object.const_get("Foo")
f.new.__send__(:bar) #=> "FOOO BAR!"
```

Which I've tried to translate to

```
module foo;
import std.stdio;

class Foo {
  void bar() {
    writeln("FOO BAR!");
  }
}

void main() {
  auto foo = Object.factory("foo.Foo");
  __traits(getMember, foo, "bar");
}
```

But that doesn't work because the compiler doesn't know what type `foo` is, so the call to `#bar` fails during compile.  Everywhere I've seen `Object.factory` used they cast it to a specific type, so

```
module foo;
import std.stdio;

class Foo {
  void bar() {
    writeln("FOO BAR!");
  }
}

void main() {
  auto foo = cast(Foo) Object.factory("foo.Foo");
  __traits(getMember, foo, "bar");
}
```

would work just fine. But if I know what I want to cast the object to what good is using `Object.factory`? That doesn't make *any* sense to me!

**UPDATE 2** I've fixed compiler issues, but now it's crashing at runtime, saying it couldn't find the method

```
module foo;
import std.stdio;

class MyDynamic {
  void call(C, T...)(C instance, string method, T args) {
    foreach(member; __traits(allMembers, C)) {
      writeln(member);
      if (member == method) {
        static if (__traits(compiles, __traits(getMember, instance, member)(args))) {
          __traits(getMember, instance, member)(args);
        }
        return;
      }
    }

    assert(0, "No method found");
  }
}

class Foo : MyDynamic {
  void bar() {
    writeln("FOO BAR!");
  }
}

void main() {
  auto foo = cast(MyDynamic) Object.factory("foo.Foo");
  assert(foo !is null);

  foo.call(foo, "bar");
}
```

**Update** For anyone coming to this question now, you can see my final solution here: https://github.com/jaredonline/action-pack

Comment: Though, at the moment my D is segfaulting and I'm not sure why.

Comment: "now it's crashing at runtime, saying it couldn't find the method" it is because `C` in your context is inferred to be `MyDynamic`, not `Foo`. It is impossible to do without some sort of `ClassInfo` help for runtime reflection.

Comment: What sort of `ClassInfo` help?

Comment: `Object.factory` internally uses http://dlang.org/phobos/object.html#.TypeInfo_Class which is default D way to do runtime reflection. I was initially thinking about hacking desired functionality by inspecting vtbl for given class instance. However, solution proposed by Adam will scale much better and is reliably type-safe so I won't go forward with actual implementation attempt ;)

Comment: @jaredonline I've actually been looking to doing something similar. Is there a specific project youre working on?

Comment: @carboncomputed I'm trying to write a router based on ActionDispatch from Rails to use with `vibe-d`

Comment: @carboncomputed You can see what I'm working on here https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/issues/444

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I do this is to build my own factory function and dynamic dispatches. Using __traits(allMembers), loop through all the supported classes and get a list of methods. Write a wrapper template that takes generic arguments and converts them to the arguments the function needs. Store a reference to the wrapper function in an associative array, or have a dispatch method in your interface to call it.

When it is time to do the work, create the class (with your own wrapper, or you could also use Object.factory and cast it to some generic interface with your dynamic dispatch function), then use the dynamic function. So something like:

```
// IMPORTANT: Object.factory needs a full name - includes the module and class name!
auto foo = cast(MyDynamic) Object.factory("mymodule.Foo");
assert(foo !is null); // Object.factory can return null if it didn't find the class
// and cast can also return null if it wasn't actually of that interface type, so gotta check

foo.call("my_method", ["arg", "arg2", ...]);
```

I updated this link with a full example, refresh if you don't see `module dynamicstuff;` at the top:

http://arsdnet.net/dcode/test46.d

loop allMembers, invoke based on a runtime string. Getting a list of all classes that implement an interface is possible too, by looping over ModuleInfo. See the bottom of the example file for a function to do it.

My web.d does this to do automatic calling of functions from the web. Long, messy code, but it does a lot. Here's the wrapper function:
https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff/blob/master/web.d#L2538

Note the use of ParameterTypeTuple!func from std.traits.

I put a lot of comments in here http://arsdnet.net/dcode/test46.d so hopefully they will answer your questions. That example briefly demonstrates:

- compile time reflection with __traits (MyDynamicImplementation)
- run time reflection with ModuleInfo and ClassInfo (getAllDynamicClasses)
- User-defined attributes (isDynamicallyAvailable)
- Calling a method with dynamic data (MyDynamicImplementation, uses ReturnType, to, ParameterTypeTuple, and there's commented code for Variant if you are interested)
- An alternative to multiple inheritance, using an interface and mixin template together.

You don't necessarily have to use all that stuff, but I figured I'd touch upon all of it since these can all be pretty useful for these url routing tasks.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I worked out from your samples and explanation, but I'm still missing some key understandings I think.

Comment: Okay, so I've fixed the compiler issues, but now I have the same issue before, I need to `cast` the object to the correct class for this to work.

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of all the classes that inherit from `MyDynamic`?

Comment: Yes, I updated this link: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/test46.d refresh it, should be > 100 lines now. Has a full example of the interface, reflection, and get list of all classe.s i'll edit the answer too

Comment: Holy moly! Thank you so much for taking the time to go into so much detail. It'll take me awhile to go through it all and make sure I understand, but I'll leave a comment here if I have any more questions. Thanks again!